# Netsuite SiteCategory searching using suitlet

Tags: netsuite

I want to Search SiteCategory at suitlet so how to load it and using search condition parentCategory = 0 and want to include in the result these fields urlcomponent, isinactive, isonline

now i am using this code

```
var custFilters = new Array();
custFilters[0]  = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid',null,'isnotempty'); 
//custFilters[1]    = new nlobjSearchFilter('parentCategory','is','0');  it give error

var custColumns = new Array(); 
custColumns[0]  = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid', null, null);  
custColumns[1]  = new nlobjSearchColumn('name', null, null);

//these line give error
//custColumns[2]    = new nlobjSearchColumn('urlcomponent', null, null);
//custColumns[3]    = new nlobjSearchColumn('isinactive', null, null);
//custColumns[4]    = new nlobjSearchColumn('isonline', null, null);


var curSearch   = nlapiCreateSearch('SiteCategory',custFilters,custColumns);
var resultSet   = curSearch.runSearch();
```

also how to skip loading the items if i load sitecategory using this code

nlapiLoadRecord('SiteCategory',curCatID);

now it load the presentationitem with items listing which make it very slow as i do not need the items data here

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you cannot do that and you'll need to find a workaround.

Perhaps the *simplest* thing is record a SuiteTalk session doing the category search where you can sub in the category id. Then submit that with saved credentials via nlapiRequestURL. I don't know if token based logins give any help here but the hardest part of that approach is securing the credentials.

The next thing to do is create a "Shadow Category" custom record. You can then create saved search that summarizes all the used category ids (from items) and then create a daily scheduled script to walk each record; load it and save the relevant details to the custom record. That way the information you need is there when you need it.

Note this doesn't work for Tab records. They way I process those is with a client script that actually loads the Tab records as xml and processes those with the nlapiSelectNode/nlapiSelectValue calls.